# Is it possible to group twice without subqueries?

Tags: sql, oracle

I answered one of the questions on SO with the following query:

```
SELECT s.address
FROM shop s 
JOIN visit v ON s.shopid = v.shopid 
JOIN customer c ON v.customerid = c.customerid 
WHERE c.cname = 'John' 
GROUP BY 
s.address
, c.customerid 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This works fine, but will return duplicate addresses if there are 2 or more John's for a given shop who meet the query's criteria, so I modified my answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.address 
FROM 
(
SELECT s.address
FROM shop s 
JOIN visit v ON s.shopid = v.shopid 
JOIN customer c ON v.customerid = c.customerid 
WHERE c.cname = 'John' 
GROUP BY 
s.address
, c.customerid 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) a
```

Now my question is: is it possible to achieve grouping first when evaluating the aggregate expression and then before selecting in a single query?

Comment: Probably use can first take distinct customers from the table where it is repeating  hen put join..

Comment: Customers in that table are distinct, the duplication occurs for shops when joining, because many John's can buy in a single store.

Comment: if u are have to take address alone then insted of taking table shop fully u can try (select distinct customerid as customerid ,adress from shop ) s then put necessary join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this directly

```
SELECT distinct s.address
FROM shop s 
JOIN visit v ON s.shopid = v.shopid 
JOIN customer c ON v.customerid = c.customerid 
WHERE c.cname = 'John' 
GROUP BY 
s.address
, c.customerid 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I think this is what you want.

The `SELECT` is the last that the RBDMS do (well, really, the order is). First will filtering and grouping, then select and then ordering.

So you could use group by, and then distinct.

No need to show the fields that you're grouping. But you can't show fields that are not grouped, or used in aggregation functions.

Comment: Oh, so distinct works just before select? That was my first idea of an answer, but I thought distinct would be evaluated earlier.

Comment: nono, after that. First where clause is evalued, after that the group, and a having (if there is one). Then, with the data collected, you can use aggregate functions, string functions, etc etc etc. A distinct is another think you can do :)